# Configuring zz_overrides.ini in Apache versus in Nginx

Tags: server, 18.04, php, nginx, apache2.4

If you work with Nginx and you want to override your PHP settings from an external file that won't get deleted or changed in updates, you can create a `/etc/php/*/fpm/zz_overrides.ini` and put your PHP env changes there.

When I worked with Nginx, I configured `zz_overrides.ini` in my environment by running this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in /etc/php/*/fpm/; do
    cat <<-"EOF" > "$dir"/zz_overrides.ini
        [PHP]
        post_max_size = 2000M
        upload_max_filesize = 2000M
        max_execution_time = 3000
    EOF
done

ln -s /etc/php/*/fpm/zz_overrides.ini /etc/php/*/fpm/conf.d/20-zz-overrides.ini
# Enable the above php.ini extension via a symlink in conf.d;
```

Now I went back working with Apache (in which I never did that task and I believe it should be quite different there due to lack of php-fpm utilization, naturally).

How should I do similar overriding in Apache?

<sub>Newcomers: Note that changing PHP.ini itself isn't effective as it will be re-written in each upgrade)</sub>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache you could can use `php_flag` directives inside a virtualhost configuration (or a `.htaccess` file inside the document root dir).

The following example mimics your current script, by creating a `./conf-available/$vhost/php_overrides.conf` with php override directives per enabled virtualhost and inserts (or updates) an `Include` directive pointing to that file (paths are Debian style, adapt to your needs):

```
apache_confdir="${apache_confdir:-/etc/apache2}"
apache_confavailable="${apache_confdir}/conf-available"
overrides_name="php_overrides.conf"
overrides=(
"post_max_size = 2000M"
"upload_max_filesize 2000M"
"max_execution_time 3000"
)
# name of the directive under which the new Include directive will be placed
parentdirective_name="DocumentRoot"
parentdirective_re="^([[:space:]]*)(${parentdirective_name}[[:space:]]+.*)$"

oldpwd="$(pwd)"
cd ${apache_confdir}/sites-enabled
for vhostconf in *.conf; do

   # construct and create/overwrite the per vhost php_overrides.conf file
   vhost_realpath="$(readlink -m "${vhostconf}")"
   vhost_realname="${vhost_realpath##*/}"
   vhost_name="${vhost_realname%*.conf}"
   vhost_confdir="${apache_confavailable}/${vhost_name}"
   [[ ! -d "${vhost_confdir}" ]] && mkdir -p "${vhost_confdir}"

   vhost_overrides="${vhost_confdir}/${overrides_name}"
   printf "php_flag %s\n" "${overrides[@]}" > ${vhost_overrides}

   # construct and insert/update the Include directive
   printf -v includedirective "Include %s" "${vhost_overrides}"
   include_re="^([[:space:]]+Include[[:space:]]+${vhost_overrides})$"
   if grep -qE "${include_re}" "${vhostconf}"; then
       sed -i "s#${include_re}#    ${includedirective}#g" "${vhost_realpath}"
   else
       declare -a directives=()
       while IFS='' read line; do
           directives+=("${line}")
           if [[ "${line}" =~ ${parentdirective_re} ]]; then
               directives+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${includedirective}")
           fi
       done<"${vhost_realpath}"
       printf "%s\n" "${directives[@]}" > "${vhost_realpath}"
   fi
done
cd "${oldpwd}"
```

However, since it seems all your virtual hosts use the same PHP overrides, it would be easier just to create a file `./conf-available/php_overrides.conf` once, include the following line in each vhost configuration, and then create or remove symlinks in  `./conf-enabled` to control if it will be used:

```
# inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/vhost1
Include /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/vhost1/*.conf
```

So to use it:

```
cd /etc/apache2/conf-enabled
mkdir vhost1
cd vhost1
ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/php_overrides.conf
```

To stop using it:

```
rm /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/vhost1/php_overrides.conf
```

Comment: Oh, shit, I didn't track this question and missed all emails in the last day and didn't see the email about the grace period for giving bounty. Sorry man !!!

Comment: Upvoted for your investation in finding way and in accordance with the circumstances !!!

Comment: I think it'll be simpler for me to either change the 2 lines of conf directly, or find some way to automate their change with a small script.